# Maximum coordinate of a linear transformation of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Given a vector $x \in R^n$ (variable) and a constant matrix $M \in \{0, 1\}^{m \times n}$ (known). $M$ is a binary matrix, meaning that its entries are either $0$ or $1$. I need to obtain an upperbound of the maximum coordinate of $M x$, denoted $\max(M x)$ where $\max(v) = \max_i v_i$. One upperbound I can think of is $$\max(M x) \leq \| M x \|_\infty \leq \| M \|_\infty \| x \|_\infty$$
but this bound seems conservative. Is there any tighter bound for this?

**EDIT:** An example of using the above bound: For any $\alpha \geq 0$, I can say that for all $x$ such that $\|x\|_\infty \leq \frac{\alpha}{\|M\|_\infty}$, $\max(M x) \leq \alpha$. But this bound is too conservative.

Comment: What is $\|M\|_\infty$, and how do you justify the last inequality?

Comment: Is there really a maximum value? If some $M\Bbb x$ has a positive cell value, then I can make another $\Bbb y=2\Bbb x$ which gives a larger $M\Bbb y$ value.

Comment: $\|M\|_\infty$ is the induced infinity-norm for the matrix $M$. The last inequality is by definition.

Comment: @peterwhy Given $x$, there exists $\max(M x)$, and I want to bound it in terms of $M$ and $x$. For example, using the above bound, I can say that for all $x$ such that $\|x\|_\infty \leq \frac{\alpha}{\|M\|_\infty}$, $\max(M x) \leq \alpha$. But this bound is too conservative.